# Is it possible to turn off the computer programmatically at a certain time?

Tags: winapi

Is it possible to turn off the computer programmatically? If so, which Windows API functions should I call?

I want to create an application that turns off the computer at a certain time. Specifically, I want to shut down my computer at 24:00.

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Comment: See [System Shutdown Functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376883%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: What aspect of this are you interested in? Shutting down programmatically? Or doing so at a specific time? And why do you need to write a program to do this when you could just make a scheduled task?

Comment: I removed the Delphi tag since I feel that this is more of a winapi question. However, I suspect that it's not really a programming question at all. Just create a task and be done with it.

Comment: I want to cut down the computer at 24:00, unless it is switched off.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan If it's not a programming question then let's close it or migrate to SuperUser.  It's clearly off-topic as you have edited it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to shut down my computer at 24:00.

You do not need to do this programmatically. Furthermore, you should not do this programmatically since it is far more complicated than using the built in operating system provided services.

What you should do is to create a scheduled operating system task that shuts down at your specified time.